# Include script in orchard cms partiall view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchard-modules

I have some partial view in Orchard CMS  that have some include, the problem is that when I include using  Script the page is not loading?

Here is my partilla view that is called

List-ProjectionWidget.cshtml

```
@using Orchard.Mvc.Html;
@using Orchard.UI.Resources;


@using (Script.Head()) {
    <style type="text/css">
        .featureSlider li { height:@(Model.Group.GroupHeight)px; width:@(Model.Group.GroupWidth)px; background-color:@(backgroundColor); }
        .featureSlider li h2, .featureSlider li h3, .featureSlider li h2 a, .featureSlider l1 p.slideNumbers { color:@(foregroundColor) !important; }
        .featureSlider li span { width:@(Model.Group.ImageWidth)px; height:@(Model.Group.ImageHeight)px; }
        .featureSlider li span img, .featureSlider li span a img { width:@(Model.Group.ImageWidth)px; height:@(Model.Group.ImageHeight)px; }
        div#slideNav a.activeSlide { background-color: @(foregroundColor); }
        .featureSlider li p { position: relative; top:@(Model.Group.GroupHeight - 25)px; }
        .headline { padding-top: @(Model.Group.HeadlineOffsetTop)px; }
        .headline, .headline + h3 { padding-left: @(Model.Group.HeadlineOffsetLeft)px; }
    </style>
}

using (Script.Foot())
{

}


@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   string text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(item.ContentItem.BodyPart.Text, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
   @text
   <br />
   foreach(var sub in item.ContentItem.SliderItem.Picture.MediaParts)
   {
       @sub.MediaUrl <br />
   }

   @item.ContentItem.SliderItem.Link.Value <br />
   @item.ContentItem.SliderItem.Link.Text <br />    
    <br />
}
```

But it does not loaing the view only blank?
If i removeScripts Head annd Foot, all is working ok?
Where is  the problem?

Comment: When you say partial view, do you mean that you're querying it through an Ajax request? If that's the case, then it's normal that scripts would not load.

Comment: Not this is not ajax :(

Comment: Pretty sure you're missing an @ sign on your Foot. Not sure if that'll help.